# Convert a .txt file and create an 3D associative array in php as a product list

Tags: php, arrays, web, associative-array, cart

I am currently a newbie in the `php` scene and have been trying to convert `.txt` file to a `3D Associative Array` that stores a list of products that will `$_POST` data to a `cart.php` and `checkout.php` page.

First Dimension
I want to get the `'Title'` of the text file to be the `$key` values of the first dimension.

Second Dimension 
Row 1 header will be the `$key` values

Third dimension will be rows matching the headers (Row 2 - Row 4) of the `products.txt` file.

An example of the desired format:

```
$products = Array
(
     ['Chain Loop Earrings'] => Array
    (
        [ID] => 100
        [OID] => 'One Size',
        [Title] => 'Chain Loop Earrings',
        [Description] =>  'Custom Designer Earrings from 
                           X Collection', 
        [Option] => 'NA'       
        [Price] => 30
    );

 ['Buckle Belt'] => Array
    (
        [ID] => 200
        [OID] => 'S',
        [Title] => 'Buckle Belt',
        [Description] =>  'Custom Designer Buckle Belt from 
                           X Collection', 
        [Option] => 'Small'       
        [Price] => 120
    );
```

This is the products.txt page:

```
ID,OID,TITLE,Description,Option,Price
100,-,Chain Loop Earrings,CUSTOM CHAIN MID * LOCALLY SOURCED 
MATERIALS * ONE-OFF PIECE ,-,30.0.0
200,-,Rope Necklace,CUSTOM CHAIN MID * LOCALLY SOURCED 
MATERIALS * ONE-OFF PIECE ,-,60.0
300,S,Buckle Belt,SZ SMALL GUN-METAL BUCKLE * PIECES by YJ 
ENGRAVING * ONE-OFF PIECE,Small,120.0
```

This array will be added to a products.php page which will be called upon by

```
echo $products['Buckle Belt']['Price'];
```

and applicable values from the array to display what item/s the user has added to their cart, and a calculation of the total cart price.

NOTE: Please no SQL, just PHP for now :)

Comment: Why no SQL? This would be soo much easier with SQL. You have essentially made a DB, it will just function inefficently and insecurly.

Comment: Because the assignment says so :(. So lame, I would otherwise!

Comment: It isn't for a realtime website, for an Assignment

Comment: Please provide a sample of your code so we can see where it is not working.

Comment: No Attempt - Too Broad